# Very Simple Crypt Program Error

Tags: c, encryption, low-level, low-level-io

I'm creating a program that takes a file as input & outputs the decrypted password of each line. The file contains three lines of encrypted passwords. I am guaranteed that the passwords decrypt to 4 letter words. Given that i have created an char[] of the letters. I'm having a problem reading the file line by line using LOW LEVEL IO and putting the resulting password in a new file. Any & all advice is appreciated!

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main(void)
{

   int f = open("pass.txt", O_RDONLY);
   if (f < 0) 
      return 0;
   char buf[1024];
   while (my_fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f)) 
      printf("%s\n", buf);
   close(f);
   const char *const pass = "$1$6gMKIopE$I.zkP2EvrXHDmApzYoV.B.";
   char *result;
   int ok;
   char guess[] = {'a','a','a','a','\0'};
   char ch1=guess[0], ch2=guess[1], ch3=guess[2], ch4=guess[3];
   do{
      for(ch1; ch1<='z';++ch1)
      {
         for(ch2='a';ch2<='z';++ch2)
         {
            for(ch3='a';ch3<='z';++ch3)
            {
               for(ch4='a';ch4<='z';++ch4)
               {
                  result = crypt(guess, pass);               
               }

            }
         }     
      }
   }while(strcmp(result, pass) != 0);
   puts(guess);
   return 0;
}

int my_fgets(char* buf, int len, int f)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++,buf++)
   {
      int count = read(f, buf, 1);
      if (!count || (buf[0] == '\n'))
      {
         buf[0] = 0;
         return i;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Text file:

```
$1$6gMKIopE$I.zkP2EvrXHDmApzYoV.B.
$1$pkMKIcvE$WQfqzTNmcQr7fqsNq7K2p0
$1$0lMKIuvE$7mOnlu6RZ/cUFRBidK7PK.
```

Comment: Does this problem you say you're having exhibit any *symptoms*?

Answer (score 0):

The following block of code appears to be flawed:

```
while (my_fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f)) 
   printf("%s\n", buf);
```

What that does is preserve only the last line. The other lines are read and discarded.

Also, it's not clear how `ch1` is supposed to be initialized to in each iteration of the `do ... while` loop. You have it as:

```
for(ch1; ch1<='z';++ch1)
//  ^^^
```

That doesn't initialize `ch1`. It's an expression with no side effects.

I suggest putting most of the logic for password decryption in a function of its own and calling the function after reading every line.

```
void decryptPassword(char* buf)
{
   printf("%s\n", buf);
   const char *const pass = "$1$6gMKIopE$I.zkP2EvrXHDmApzYoV.B.";
   char *result;
   int ok;
   char guess[] = {'a','a','a','a','\0'};
   char ch1=guess[0], ch2=guess[1], ch3=guess[2], ch4=guess[3];
   do{
      for(ch1; ch1<='z';++ch1)
      {
         for(ch2='a';ch2<='z';++ch2)
         {
            for(ch3='a';ch3<='z';++ch3)
            {
               for(ch4='a';ch4<='z';++ch4)
               {
                  result = crypt(guess, pass);               
               }
            }
         }     
      }
   }while(strcmp(result, pass) != 0);
   puts(guess);
}

int main(void)
{
   int f = open("soc.in", O_RDONLY);
   if (f < 0) 
      return 0;
   char buf[1024];
   while (my_fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f)) 
      decryptPassword(buf);
   close(f);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @r sahu Ignore the constant pass char. that was only for testing purposes. So would i compare crypt like crypt(guess, buf) instead?

Comment: I am not up to snuff with how to use `crypt`.

Comment: I get an error when calling the my_fgets for some reason